# Full Calendar Display issue

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have implemented full calendar using fullcalendar.js v1.5.3

Earlier I was concatenating events to a string and return the response from handler. which was displaying result as expected. string return is

[{id: '6',title: 'Dainik Jagran, Lucknow, 21 Jan. 2013',start:  1413311400,end: 1413311400,allDay:true,description: 'Award Ceremony in Lucknow, 21 Jan. 2013'},{id: '7',title: 'Dainik Jagran, Lucknow, 21 Jan. 2014',start:  1412620200,end: 1412620200,allDay:true,description: 'Award Ceremony in Lucknow, 21 Jan. 2014'},{id: '8',title: 'Dainik Jagran, Lucknow, 21 Jan. 2014',start:  1413271800,end: 1413280800,allDay:false,description: 'Award Ceremony in London, 21 Jan. 2014'}]

[image]

but later on I return the serialized string. I have written following code.

```
        foreach (CalendarEvent cevent in EventDAO.getEvents(start, end))
    {
        eventList.Add(new BadCalendarEvent
        {
            id=cevent.id,
            title=cevent.title,
            start = ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.start),
            end = ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.end),
            allDay = GetDay(cevent),
            description = cevent.description 
        }); 
        idList.Add(cevent.id);
    }

    result = serializer.Serialize(eventList);
    context.Session["idList"] = idList;

    context.Response.Write(result);
```

string return is

[{"id":6,"title":"Dainik Jagran, Lucknow, 21 Jan. 2013","description":"Award Ceremony in Lucknow, 21 Jan. 2013","start":1413311400,"end":1413311400,"allDay":"true"},{"id":7,"title":"Dainik Jagran, Lucknow, 21 Jan. 2014","description":"Award Ceremony in Lucknow, 21 Jan. 2014","start":1412620200,"end":1412620200,"allDay":"true"},{"id":8,"title":"Dainik Jagran, Lucknow, 21 Jan. 2014","description":"Award Ceremony in London, 21 Jan. 2014","start":1413271800,"end":1413280800,"allDay":"false"}]
But I am getting following result

[image]

I could not able to see the event in its specified time slot. what went wrong after returning serialized string ?

Comment: I have return allDay value to boolean type instead of string and problem got solved.

Comment: Could you explain why you're using a timestamp as start and end? `DateTime.ToString()` should work just fine.